# NSXMLParser input with incomplete strings

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsxmlparser

Here is my code:

.h

```
NSMutableString *dmxCharacters;
NSXMLParser *parser;
```

.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] init];
}

- (void) receivedData:(NSString *)data {

NSData *data2 = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data2];
[parser setDelegate:(id)self];
[parser parse];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    dmxCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:500];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    [dmxCharacters appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    NSRunAlertPanel(@"", dmxCharacters, @"", @"", @"");

}
```

receivedData:(NSString*)data is called when data is received over the serial port. I have basic XML data coming in. The serial data is coming in as :`<DMX>255,23,1,4,6</DMX>` problem is, it's not coming in as one unified string. It comes in pieces. Like, `<DM` , `X>255` , `,23,1,4,` , etc. It's random so I can't track it. Sometimes it sends the whole thing, others it sends every couple characters at a time.

I added an NSLog (to export string) in here: `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` and it's giving me "255,23,1" or "255,23,1,4" it's not getting the whole thing. Plus, didEndElement is never called. I think it's because I keep reinitiating the NSXMLParser and when the serial data is coming in after  it's not properly starting the parsing. It's hard to explain.

Any work arounds? Ways to not reinitiate the NSXMLParser, but rather add data to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure is:

**1.** Allocate a new string to contain the value for the new tag when didStartElement gets called;
 **2.** Keep concatenating each piece of the string that you get in the foundCharacters method (yes, foundCharacters just return partial strings that you have to concatenate, not the whole string);
 **3.** Copy somewhere the string when the didEndElement method gets called.

**EDIT**

Thinking well you are doing that procedure, but you aren't initializing the parser with an unique piece of data containing all the data.
So at your place I would use NSMutableData to append each piece of data, and then initialize the parser only when have the full data:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData* data; // not synthesizing it

- (void) receivedData:(NSString *)data 
{

    NSData *data2 = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.data appendData: data2];
}
```

The problem is: have you got a way to check when all the data is received?

Comment: There is a way to know when you have received the full data? I believe that didEndElement may not be called: if you receive a half closed tag that's a problem.You should initialize the parser with the whole xml data.

Comment: Nope - because it's constant. I see where you're going with this, but it's a constant thing.

Comment: The XML parser just read tags, if it receives a half tag it's a problem.Then I suggest to read it as a string (convert NSData into NSString) to know when the last tag is closed.When you read the last tag in the xml file and you are sure that the data is all, make the parser start.